# php bool function returns string instead of bool

Tags: php, string, class, boolean

I have a php Form class designed to validate form input. However, I've run into some unexpected behavior when implementing an `isEmailEmpty()` function. Here is my code:

```
class Form {
var $userEmail;
var $userPassword;
var $hashedPassword;
var $requiredPassLength = 6;

public function __construct($userEmail, $userPassword) {
    $this->userEmail = $this->cleanInput($userEmail);
    $this->userPassword = $this->cleanInput($userPassword);
}

public function cleanInput($dataField) {
    $dataField = trim($dataField);
    $dataField = stripslashes($dataField);
    $dataField = htmlspecialchars($dataField);
    return $dataField;
}

public function isEmailEmpty() {
    return ($this->userEmail == "" || $this->userEmail == null) ? true : false;
}

public function isPasswordEmpty() {
    return ($this->userPassword == "" || $this->userPassword == null) ? true : false;
}

public function isEmailValid() {
    return filter_var($this->userEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}

public function isPasswordValid() {
    return (strlen($this->userPassword) >= $this->requiredPassLength) ? true : false;
}

public function hashPassword() {
    return $this->hashedPassword = password_hash($this->userPassword, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
}
// More functions down here...
```

Now, lets say I've instantiated an object in the following way:

```
$userEmail = "example@example.com";
$userPassword = "rootatoot";
$form = new Form($userEmail, $userPassword);
```

Since my `isEmailValid()` function returns a bool, I expect to receive a boolean return value, i.e, true/false or 1/0 upon excecution. However, that is not the case. Instead, when the expression evaluates to true, I get a string output of the email value tested. For instance, given the object instantiated above, the statement `echo $form->isEmailValid()` outputs `example@example.com`. Running `gettype($form->isEmailValid)` returns `string`, which also was not expected. What's even more curious: the `isPasswordValid()` function does NOT behave this way. Running `$form->isPasswordValid()` returns `1` if the password is in fact valid. Running `gettype($form->isPasswordValid())` returns `boolean`, as expected. It's also interesting that my code still works as expected. For instance, the block

```
if ($form->isEmailValid()) {
      echo "Valid email";
} else {
      echo "Invalid email";
}
```

always gives the correct output. Even though my code is running as expected, it's still important to understand what's happening behind the scenes and why. So, my questions regarding this behavior are:

1. What is responsible for a bool function returning a string? For instance, was this by design or a byproduct of some other process?
2. Are there any scenarios where this unexpected return value can cause a problem? Or does the system understand this evaluation and always handles it as accordingly? My code works fine now, but I don't think its far-fetched to anticipate unexpected return values causing some issues sooner or later.

I appreciate any information you can provide. Thanks!

Comment: `filter_var` returns a boolean false if your filter fails; otherwise it returns the filtered data - http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since my isEmailValid() function returns a bool

Well, **no, it doesn't**.

From [the documentation of `filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php):

> Returns the filtered data, or `FALSE` if the filter fails.

Your `if` logic still worked because a non-empty string is "truthy", meaning [it will be treated the same as `true`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) [when used as a condition](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php).

In order to have `isEmailValid` *actually* return a boolean, you can change your code to this:

```
public function isEmailValid()
{
   return filter_var($this->userEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== FALSE;
}
```

Comment: I see. If I execute the function with an invalid email input, nothing is output. Not even 'FALSE'. Does no output automatically evaluate to false?

Comment: @wheresmyspaceship When `false` is converted to a string by `echo`, it becomes an empty string. Use `var_dump()` if you want to see the words `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

`filter_var` doesn't return a boolean, it returns the value if it's valid, otherwise it returns `false`. So you can rewrite your function as:

```
public function isEmailValid() {
    return !!filter_var($this->userEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}
```

Using `!` twice will convert the value into a boolean.

Or, like your other functions, you can write:

```
public function isEmailValid() {
    return filter_var($this->userEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? true : false;
}
```

You don't need the conditional operator in the other functions, because they use operators that *do* return booleans, e.g. you could write:

```
public function isEmailEmpty() {
    return ($this->userEmail == "" || $this->userEmail == null);
}
```

To answer your second question, it shouldn't be a problem if you always use your function in boolean contexts, such as `if()`. No valid email should ever be falsy.